# Identify soundtrack from "Jiro Dreams of Sushi"

Tags: identify-this-song, soundtrack

I'm not sure if this is the correct place for this, but I'm looking for identification of a song I heard in a movie.

In *Jiro Dreams of Sushi* there is a scene about 23 minutes when he's on the train and a piece of music is played in the background. I've managed to extract and isolate the audio, which can be found [here](https://instaud.io/1D4c). The main violin melody starts about 30 seconds into the clip.

The piece sounds extremely familiar so I'm wondering:

1) what the name of the piece is

2) what other modern movies have used the same piece of music?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This song is [*This Bitter Earth/On The Nature Of Daylight* by Dinah Washington & Max Richter](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CW-GMG6xhtY) and comes notably from the movies:

- *Shutter Island* (2010)
- The french movie called *La French* (2014) translated *The Connection* in some countries.